# count the total number of strings in a column

Tags: python, perl, awk

I would like to count the unique lines across multiple files:

**f1.txt**

```
2039-177 GRAPE
2039-177 GRAPE
2039-176 GRAPE
2039-176 GRAPE
234-450  APPLE
```

**f2.txt**

```
690-346 MANGO
690-346 MANGO
347-348 GRAPE
4350-350 MANGO
```

**Desired Output**

```
Total no:of grapes  - 3
Total no:of mangoes - 2
Total no:of apples  - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure Perl:

```
$ perl -lane '$seen{$_}++ or ++$n{lc $F[1]};
  END{print "Total no:of ${_}s - $n{$_}"
        for sort { $n{$b} <=> $n{$a} } keys %n}' f1.txt f2.txt
Total no:of grapes - 3
Total no:of mangos - 2
Total no:of apples - 1
```

Pipeline:

```
$ cat f1.txt f2.txt | uniq | \
  perl -lanE '++$n{lc$F[1]};END{say"Total no:of ${_}s - $n{$_}"for keys%n}' | \
  sort -nrk5
Total no:of grapes - 3
Total no:of mangos - 2
Total no:of apples - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps? (Untested.)

This solution expects the names of the input files as parameters on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Utils 'max';

my %count;
$count{ (split)[1] }++ while <>;

my $len = 1 + max map length, keys %count;

for (keys %count) {
    printf "Total no:of %-*s - %d\n", $len, lc $_.'s', $count{$_};
}
```